# R before TH sound?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, sound-change

Most of time when I say a word with r before θ or ð, my tongue slides on my palate and it goes to down mouth, behind my lower teeth. This movement produce a sound similar with tap or click, sometimes the tongue don't go until down, but yet produce this different sound.
I just can produce the sound properly when I say very carefully, what I think a bad behavior, because my brain need to learn do unconscious.

It's more common when I say the r before ð.

The R and the TH are okay, because R I have on my language and the TH I have learned practicing a lot.

Saying "More than four thieves" is a pretty difficult without thinking.

This noise is common when we say very fast?

Thank you ^^

Comment: It's not necessary for an American English postvocalic /r/ to touch the palate at all, even in a rhotic idiolect. If your tongue is retroflexed, it will simply produce an "R-colored vowel" without touching the palate, and then can simply drop down to the bottom of the upper incisors (**not** the lower incisors -- interdental fricatives touch the top teeth). A light tap of the tongue apex on the bottom of the upper incisors is sufficient to produce an interdental fricative.

Comment: @jlawler
I really don't touch on palate, I just do the normal r, but in the path between R and TH my tongue slide and sometimes goes down, when say very fast.
Try to say "More than" very fast.
I really can't explain what is that.

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: @musicallinguist
Brazillian Portuguese, southern accent, we have the retroflex R, but this just happens when very fast.